# Base type vs base class

Tags: java

Ok, so this question will probably get closed, but hell, its 4:30 in the morning and I can't sleep because I'm still frustrated with my Java midterm last night.  The test was an on-line thing and you get to see how you did immediately.

The test was poorly written with tons of typos and grammatical errors.  I don't normally care about that, except that when you add in vaguely phrased questions you aren't sure how to interpret the question anymore, since you can't assume you can parse it according to the normal rules of English.

One particular question that sticks in my craw:

What is the base type for Collections?  (It was written like that, with the capital C, which I think is important.)

The only two relevant possibilities were Object and Collections.  Now I know that Collections is the class from which most of the collection classes derive, so I initially selected that.  On my second run-through I thought, wait a minute. By base type, does he mean what is the base class from which Collections derives? (After all, by capitalizing the C it indicated Collections class in a specific sense, rather than just collections in a generic sense.) So I changed my answer to Object, because I know that Collections extends Object.

Turns out I was right the first time.

So my question, then: if I kvetch about this question, do I have a leg to stand on?  Or am I missing some distinction between base type and base class?

Comment: If this was a midterm, couldn't you email the instructor for clarification?

Comment: If the "correct" answer was that "Collections" for the "base type for Collections", that is obviously wrong. The base type for the "Collections" class is "Object". See Jon's answer for more clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the question had a spelling error, and the c should have been lowercase: The base type for *most* collection classes is the [`Collection<E>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) interface.

If the question was spelt properly (capitalized 'C' intended and not a typo): The base type of the `Collections` class is `Object`.

I'd say the question is poorly phrased anyway.

Comment: And that was my thought process, and why I had gone with Collection first.  But then I overthought it.  Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 5):

> Now I know that Collections is the class from which most of the collection classes derive, so I initially selected that.

Well that's a problem to start with... because it isn't. [`Collections`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) is a utility class with only a private constructor, with *no* subclasses.

`Collections` does have `Object` as a superclass, but *it* isn't a superclass for anything. The highest level class (other than `Object`) which many collections derive from is [`AbstractCollection`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html), which then has `AbstractList` etc as subclasses.

It sounds like it was a bad question, but your own understanding was flawed too. Sounds like a no-score draw, but you should possibly raise the test quality with someone.

Comment: Thanks for this Jon. I just checked the API again, and you've taught me something I didn't really know.  I've used ArrayList extensively but never really paid attention to the hierarchy.  There may have also been some confusion on my part between the Collections class, and the Collection interface.  Oh well, I may have got the question wrong, but I have a better understanding of it now!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the question is actually asking about the main/base types of java collection framework. the Types here would be like Set, List, Queue.. but not in context SuperType, SuperClass.